# angular ui-select2 not set value in edit mode

Tags: angularjs, ui-select, ui-select2, angular-ui-select

```
<select id="e1" style="width:100%" ui-select2  tabindex="-1" ng-init="GetAllAgent()" ng-model="Agent" ng-options="ctr as ctr.AgentName for ctr in ListAgent track by ctr.AgentId" ng-change="GetSubAgentList(Agent.AgentId)">
<option value=""> </option></select>
```

when it is in edit mode,could not set the default value using the below code

```
 angular.forEach($scope.ListAgent, function (value, index) {            
            if (value.AgentId == HR.AgentId) {
                $scope.Agent = $scope.ListAgent[index];
            }
        })

 $scope.ListAgent= [{ AgentId: "0", AgentName:"Ann" }, {  AgentId: "1", AgentName:"Muh" }];
```

and

```
HR.AgentId=1
```

Comment: please post `$scope.ListAgent` and `HR.AgentId` or post demo in Plunker

Comment: Questn edited.If thre any anthr method to set dropdwn value  pls share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, `ui-select2` does not support `ng-options`: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2/issues/252

Further, `ui-select2` does not work with `ng-repeat`: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2/issues/162

The solution is to use `input`:

```
 <input ui-select2="select2Options" ng-model="Agent"/>
```

where `select2Options` is:

```
$scope.select2Options = {
  data:$scope.ListAgent
}
```

The list should have structure: `[{id,text}]` so `$scope.ListAgent` will be

```
 $scope.ListAgent= [{ id:0, text:"Ann" }, { id:1, text:"Muh" }];
```

[Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Dsi2KwiVAhDAcC3Oc4Io?p=preview)

---

For place holder add `data-placeholder="----"`

Comment: But here`ng-options` support `ui-select2` and dropdown is working.Getting AgentId using `$scope.Agent.AgentId`..So why it is not working edit mode as normal `select`

Comment: using your solution when more than one select use in a page what wil be the `$scope.select2Options = {
  data:$scope.ListAgent
}`

Comment: @safeenarasak `$scope.select2Options` ... `$scope.select2OptionsTwo` ....

Comment: if I change `$scope.ListAgent` to from db list using ` $scope.GetAllAgent = function () {
        $http({
            method: "get",
            url: "/api/Agent/GetAllAgent"
        }).then(function (response) {
                       $scope.ListAgent = response.data;
          
        })
    };` dropdown could not bind